# My ng-option don't work

Tags: angularjs

i am beginner in Angularjs and i have a question.

1. Look this:

   ```
   <div ng-init = " listEmail = 
   [
   {name:'Helton', email:'email@email.com', type:'A'},
   {types: ['A', 'B', ' ']} 
   ]">
   </div>
   ```
2. and this:

   ```
   <div class="email-view" data-ng-repeat="lista in listEmail| filter: selectName |
   orderBy:'-id':true">

           <select ng-model="lista.type" ng-options="c.types for c in listEmail.types">
                   <option value=""></option>
           </select>

           <input type="text" value="{{lista.email}}" name="{{lista.name}}" style="border:0;">

   </div>
   ```
3. I would like to get a result like this:

   ```
   <select>
           <option value=""></option>
           <option value="A" selected></option>
           <option value="B"></option>
   </select>
   ```

Sorry for my wrong english.

Comment: Your listEmail is an array. Just use `listEmail[0].types` in your ng-options.

Comment: I think @Beterraba meant `listEmail[1].types`, Also I don't think the `' '` value will work as expected to get the desired output

Comment: @TheSharpieOne You are right. I dont know why I think that the two objects was a single entry in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your comprehension statement should be: `c.types for c in listEmail[1].types`

Comment: Its one character change so I cannot edit... but `listEmail[0].types` should be `listEmail[1].types`

Comment: Also 'compression' should be 'comprehension' but couldn't edit for some reason.